# SQL-Retrieve only the Total count of occurences of a specific column

Tags: sql

Trying to get the result of count=4 i.e Total occurences of 'true' and false' values in the table

Below is the test table

```
| id | state | value |
|  1 | CH    | true  |
|  2 | NY    | false |
|  3 | GH    | true  |
|  4 | ZY    | false |
```

Expected Output: 4

Attempted the below SQL query but I know its messed up:

```
select count(*) from test where value=true and value= false

select sum(value) from test where value=true and value= false
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Can value be anything other than `true`/`false`?  Just use `count(*)`.

Comment: count * produces 0 results, had tried it

Comment: Well obviously, the `value` column cannot be both TRUE and FALSE at the same time, just like a switch cannot be both ON and OFF

Comment: well I need to get a output of 4 by combining the results of value=true and value=false ..... in a single query

Comment: If there can't be any other values in that column this is as simple as `select count(value) from test` which will not count NULL values

Comment: Actually I need the where condition mandatory in the query since depending on the count of true and false summed together will then be used in the assertion to verify against the expected count of boolean values